# Are there any guidelines for the indoor air quality exposure limits for newborns or infants?

Tags: air-quality, infant

Are there any guidelines for the indoor air quality exposure limits for newborns or infants?
I would like to find the guidelines for the indoor air quality parameters such as:

- Temperature
- Relative Humidity
- Formaldehyde
- Particle matters (PM2.5, PM0.1 ,..)

Comment: Please spell out PM. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Better, but now you've used new abbreviations without explanation. What does PM2.5, PM0.1 mean?